# Docusign signer coordinates not working properly

Tags: docusignapi

[image]

**Image 1 - Pdf opened in browser, it locates mouse pointer location. Signer tab should have been placed next to "Hello" (x-142, y-111 pixels)**
[image]
**Image 2 - Docusign placed tab here instead**

Comment: what version of the eSignature API do you use? 2.0 or 2.1?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this and share the same?

Answer (score 0):

x/y positioning via absolute specification is off in v2 of the API. V2.1 is much better at this.

Or even better, use anchor text positioning when you can.